# Category Blog Pagination URL Rewriting in Joomla 3.X

Tags: joomla

I have facing two issues in the Joomla 3.X regarding the rewrite the URL of Category Blog pagination.

Problem 1. "?start=6 OR ?limitstart=6" to "/page/6"

Problem 2: By default in category blog pagination url it uses limit value for eg. if i have to set 5 articles in a page then on page 2 the url is ?start=6, I want the URL is /page/2.

Early response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla! cannot do this out of the box. You will need an SEO plugin to accomplish this. [sh404sef](https://weeblr.com/joomla-seo-analytics-security/sh404sef) should be able to handle it.